# how to switch maven local repository cache when git branch is switched

Tags: git, maven

I use maven and git in a project. The git repository contains a maven project with several subprojects in separate directories with own pom files. I use git local branches and I switch between these branches quite often. Whenever I switch the git local branch I need to call `mvn install` to refresh the local maven  repository cache in `$HOME/.m2`. The git branch switch is fast but the local local maven cache rebuild takes more than 20 minutes. If I do not rebuild it then a subproject build fails because the subprojects depends on other subprojects.

My intention is to create a git hook for post-merge and make a separate maven repository cache for each branch. The git hook then can call something like `ln -s branch-specific-cache $HOME/.m2`.

But I think that such a solution must already exist and I do not want to invent a wheel. Is there an existing mechanism that allows following?

- change the local maven cache when a git branch is changed
- create a copy of the local maven cache when a git branch is created

Comment: May I ask are these various branches uses different _versions_ of the same JAR dependencies?  If not, then why not just have everything share a common local repository?

Comment: Various branches use different versions of jars because they are built from the branch. But they are always named 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. The `mvn install` always copy version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to the local artifactory and pom files contain links to versions 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Please stop calling local maven cache "artifactory" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments I created a git `post-checkout` hook. I have a directory for each branch in my home `$HOME/.m2.branch-name/subproject`. The maven cache contains a symbolic link to the directory according to the branch that I see in git repository.

The `post-checkout` hook either creates a symbolic link if the directory for the newly selected branch already exists or creates the directory and copies data from previously selected branch. The first case is fast. The second case takes a long time because of copying but it is done only once when a new branch is created and checked out.

The hook script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

project=$HOME/.m2/repository/com/mycompany
subproject=mysubproject
newbranch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
m2newbranch=~/.m2.$newbranch

if [ -d "$m2newbranch" ]
then
    ln -sf "$m2newbranch/$subproject" "$project"
else
    mkdir -p "$m2newbranch/$subproject"
    cp -R "$project/$subproject/"* "$m2newbranch/$subproject"
    ln -sf "$m2newbranch/$subproject" "$project"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this as a separate answer, since I think it is really the cleanest and simplest solution, plus there are no "tricks" using multiple local maven repositories.

In short - you need to use a different artifact versioning in each branch. A simple convention could be: `BRANCH-X.Y.Z[-SNAPSHOT]`.

For example:

- `develop` branch: `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`
- `abc` branch: `<version>ABC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`
- `xyz` branch: `<version>XYZ-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`
- (and so on)

Maven is quite capable of operating with such versioning, and you can do this in the same repo, without the branch artifacts stepping on each others' toes.

Note that I have tested this locally, with my project versions being `1.16-SNAPSHOT` in develop and `SQLSERVER-1.16-SNAPSHOT` in `sqlserver` branch and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work well in my case. I do not want update pom files. Pom files are project files and I occasionally need to change some of them and push them back to origin or other remotes. And the branches I have are local branches.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hacky, but you could try something like this (haven't tested it).

- Set your $M2_HOME to a location *inside* your git project
- From there, add a `conf/settings.xml` file
- Set `<localRepository>` to some place *outside* the git project

In this way, every time you change branches you are changing the `settings.xml` and maven should operate differently when you run `mvn ...`

Please note that I haven't tested it, and it's extremely "hacky", but it should give you some ideas.

Comment: Good hint! I am upvoting but still hope I will found something that is tested and works because I guess I am not the first one facing this issue.

Comment: Added a comment, regarding versioning - did you try that already, if it didn't work, why not? Regarding this (second) suggestion, I have tested this and it works, maven 3.2.5 and IntelliJ 14

Comment: The proposed solution works but I cannot use it. I would need to add the `settings.xml` to git repository and it is not acceptable in my project. Or I would need to update `settings.xml` on each checkout. Well it is faster than rebuild local maven chache but still not convenient.

Comment: Please take a look at where I moved my suggestions from this answer into a separate answer - I really think that is the better answer. Please let me know if you manage to try it.